# Using .where query to retrieve single document in Cloud Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection of Firestore documents that are named in a manner that makes it easy for me to identify them whilst looking at them in the Firebase console. The documents themselves contain an ID property (with a unique value) that I COULD use as the document name, at the expense of being able to instantly identify which is which.

I am wondering if there is anything particularly bad (other than inelegance) about querying this list of documents for the ID property using `.where` and always using the first item in the returned array?

```
db().collection
  .collection('my-collection')
  .where('id', '==', selectedId)
  .get()
  .then(function (querySnapshot){
    const selectedItem = querySnapshot[0].data()
    resolve(selectedItem)
  })
```

Am I better off sacrificing readability on the database end for cleaner code/better performance? I assume I'll be doing a fair amount of perusing the database directly, at least until I have coded a method of interacting with the backend data via an interface.

Thanks for your time. Apologies if I've missed something obvious.

Comment: while using the where query you only get the document which have the property you mentioned in the query

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Since you know the document ID, why don't you just load it with `db().collection('my-collection').doc(selectedId)`?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen, it's purely because when I am looking at this particular collection in the Firebase console, I can much easier identify each document by a descriptive name as opposed to them all being a relatively arbitrary ID.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen the document ID I am using gives a plain English indication of two pieces of data related to the document (the name of the object within the document AND the name of the group of objects to which it belongs), both of which would otherwise only be indicated by numeric ID's when viewing in the console.

Can you confirm whether or not there is any performance impact for querying a single item using .where as opposed to accessing directly? Thanks for your time.

Comment: If you know the parts that make up the document ID, why don't you just read the document by its ID with `db().collection('my-collection').doc(selectedId)`?